# wordpress - want to connect my ABOR(Austin Board of Realtors)website to RETS Matrix

Tags: wordpress, rets, idx

I'm developing a website about ABOR(Austin Board of Realtors) in wordpress, how to connect RETS Matrix to our website so, then we get data from MLS?

Answer (score 0):

The easy and quick solution 
1: Use a Wordpress Plugin, I have had great results using [IMPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/idx-broker-platinum/)

Yet another way is connect using Wordpess restful API, you would need to GET listings from your MLS, and have something set to update listings so UPDATE, and if your trying to post to MLS from WordPress using POST. There is a handy guide to help with this [REST API Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/)

To grab a listing something like this:

curl http://somelinktomls.com/api/path/< type>

Comment: **IMPRESS** is for IDX Broker
I need in RETS Matrix

Comment: Lol then Google a WordPress plugin that suits your needs there is tons of what your looking for or look into API. Good luck.

Comment: Look for https://mlsimport.com/ - is a wordpress plugin that may help you